# what happened to getrefcount of a numpy array when you reshape it

Tags: python

what happened in the memory block when you reshape a np.array?

once I do sys.gerefcount. I get difference results of print(sys.getrefcount(foo2)) and print(sys.getrefcount(foo1))

```
foo1 = np.array([1,2,3])
foo2 = foo1.reshape(3,1)

print(sys.getrefcount(foo1))
print(sys.getrefcount(foo2))
```

Comment: welcome to stack overflow, why do you not add the outcome of the print? this would be easier ofr us?

Comment: They're different objects. Why would you expect them to have the same refcount?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `foo2` keeps a internal reference to `foo` (it is not the owner of the array data), so it will have 1 more additional reference in total.

The next code

```py
import numpy as np
import sys

foo1 = np.array([1,2,3])
foo2 = foo1.reshape(3,1)

print(sys.getrefcount(foo1), sys.getrefcount(foo2))
```

Produce this result:

```sh
3 2
```

Now, test this:

```py
foo1 = np.array([1,2,3])
foo2 = foo1.reshape(3,1).copy()

print(sys.getrefcount(foo1), sys.getrefcount(foo2))
```

The output is: `2 2`, because now `foo2` have its own data after making a copy of `foo` contents and the reference count of `foo` is decremented.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that:

```
print(sys.getrefcount(foo1))
2
print(sys.getrefcount(foo2))
3
```

based on the documentation:

```
sys.getrefcount(object)

    Return the reference count of the object. The count returned is generally one higher than you might expect, because it includes the (temporary) reference as an argument to getrefcount().
```

With your command: `foo2 = foo1.reshape(3,1)`you refer to object 1, so in total this leads to 3 references